# Loop that compiles and runs in int main function wont compile when put into a separate function

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with a loop in my function not compiling.  I suspect that it has to do with the fact that it involves strings in the condition, but I am not sure.

Here is the function that wont compile

```
int numWins(string team_array, string str)
{
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while (i <= 119) {
        if (str == team_array[i]) {
            count += 1;
        }
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

The part that I am having trouble with is the condition in the if statement.  I get a ton of errors when trying to compile with that line.

However, the loop does compile when it is in my int main function like this

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int count;
    string teams[120];
    string uteam;

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("worldserieswinners.txt");

    if (infile.fail()) //if the input file failed to open
    {
        cout << "input file did not open" << endl;
        exit(-1); //stop execution of the program immediately
    }

    string str;
    while (i <= 118) //might need to be 119
    {
        getline(infile, str);
        teams[i] = str;
        i += 1;
    }
    cout << "Enter a team: ";
    getline(cin, str);
    count = 0;
    i = 0;
    while (i <= 119) {
        if (str == teams[i]) {
            count += 1;
        }
        i += 1;
    }
    cout << "The " << str << " have won the World Series " << count << " time(s).";
}
```

When the loop is like this, it returns the proper value just fine for the output with no errors.  Any suggestions?

Edit: Specific compiler error I am getting is:

[Error] no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' and 'char')

Comment: Can you show your compilation error? Note also you don't return anything from `numWins`

Comment: The compiler errors are right on your screen in front of you. There is absolutely no reason to fail to include them in your question here. If you want us to **donate our time** to solve **your problem**, give us the necessary information to do so.There's no excuse to fail to do so.

Comment: and what is worse, you haven't actually provided the full code that has the issues. How can we know how you've altered `main` to call `numWins`?

Comment: @John3136 Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int numWins (string team_array, string str)
```

This function takes two parameters, both of them are strings.

```
if (str == team_array[i])
```

`str` is a `std::string`, `team_array[i]` is a `char`. An entire `std::string` cannot be compared to a single `char`.

The `team_array` parameter should probably be a `string *team_array` or a `string team_array[]`.

Comment: It probably be a good idea to mention that control will flow off of the end of his non-void function due to his absence of return.